# PHP/JavaScript Заменить JavaScript на PHP

Tags: javascript, php, вёрстка, input, backend

Всем привет, есть такой скрипт

```
    <form action="form.php" method="post" id="form">
        <input type="text">
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="lol" id="lol">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" style="display: none;">
    </form>
    <script>
        (function (target) {
            var form = document.querySelector(target);
            var submit = document.querySelector(target + ' input[type=submit]').style;
            var children = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(target + ' *'))
                .filter(child => child instanceof HTMLInputElement && child.type !== "submit" ||
                    child instanceof HTMLTextAreaElement);
            var length = children.length;
            var initialValues = children.map(child => child.value);
            for (var index = 0; index < length; index++) {
                children[index].oninput = function () {
                    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                        if (initialValues[i] !== children[i].value) {
                            submit.display = 'block';
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    submit.display = 'none';
                }
            }
        })('#form'/* or any other*/);
    </script>
```

Да он работает, но у меня сайт на PHP и есть некие  неудобства в его использовании.
Так вот вопрос есть ли функция в php, чтобы отслеживать изменения в инпуте?
Я хочу чтобы когда были внесены изменения в инпуте высвечивалась кнопка "сохранить".

Comment: Почитай, что такое PHP, где и в какой момент он выполняется

Comment: Вот тут например http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke